# Magento 2: Get collection issue in admin grid

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

I face one issue when get collection in admin grid.

```
Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\VendorTest\ModuleTest\TestCollection::getMainTable()
```

> **Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_test_grid_vendor_test_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\VendorTest\ModuleTest\TestCollection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Storage\Meta">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="dateTime" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\vendor_test_grid_vendor_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_test_grid_vendor_test.vendor_test_grid_vendor_test_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_test_grid_vendor_test.vendor_test_grid_vendor_test_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="vendor_test_grid_vendor_test_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_test_grid_vendor_test_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">hash</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">hash</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">hash</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="columns">
        <column name="catId">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="storeId">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 0):

change di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_index_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string"><vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\<modeilName>\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="<vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\<modelName>\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_module</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">test__grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">test_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string"><vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\<modelName></argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Can I get collection without mention mainTable name?

Comment: i don't think so, How would magento know about table if you don't mention name.

Comment: I think, it is possible.

Comment: If you got solution then please post it here. else you can apply my solution and accept answer. that would help.

Comment: Yes, sure. I will update here when got a proper solution for that.